# How to develop android apps on linux without android studio?

Tags: android, c++, linux

most guides on building applications for android are for android studio or outdated eclipse plug in so i was wondering is there a way to build a c++ android application without using android studio on Debian?

Comment: I think u can use Qt. https://www.qt.io/

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org) is a good one to devolop android apps. If you don't like *Eclipse* than you can try [Phonegap](https://phonegap.com/). You can follow the [guide](https://dasunhegoda.com/installrun-phonegap-ubuntu/797/) if you have trouble to install *Phonegap* in *Linux*.

You can also try [QT](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers).

There are also many websites where you can create apps like:

- [Thunkable](https://thunkable.com/#/)
- [Appsgeyser](https://www.appsgeyser.com/)
- [Appypie](https://www.appypie.com/)

Appypie, Appsgeyser, Thunkable etc.